# Ruby on Rails MySQL2::ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I am new to rails development and I have created a new project using Rubymine and whilst trying to run the project I get this error.

MySQL2::ERROR
Plugin '*E5E441046930EED0067C126B396467880C89392E' is not loaded.

As you can see not very helpful plugin description for someone who is new to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Jason

Comment: Check if **Mysql** is installed, then `gem install mysql2`

Comment: Check in your Gemfile `gem 'mysql2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure the mysql2 gem is in your gemfile:
`gem "mysql2"`

Then, run `bundle install` again to check if it successfully installed.

Afterwards make sure your `database.yml` looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: your_db_name
  username: database_username
  password: the_password
```

Now you should be covered. Make sure that all your servers instances are closed.